# How to return an extra column in a sub query that is a UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to somehow get the Promotions Id from the second select in a UNION which is a sub query that brings back one column.

Is it somehow possible to achieve this or will I have to duplicate the 2nd query somehow again?

**Updated**

So, basically this code will get a Promotion Price from an older Table in the same Database and then it will UNION it to a new Promotions Table and select the best or lowest price from the two, but the newer Promotion Table has a Promotion Id (P.Id) which I need to return.

**Additional Unrelated Info**

The DateValidFrom and DateValidTo is of type Datetime because the Promotion can have a start and end date with a specific time.

**Expected Outcome**

I want to return the Promotions Id which is P.Id from the Promotions Table.

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCustomerPricingForProduct] (@StockParentId int,
                                                     @CustomerCode varchar(30),
                                                     @PricingDate date,
                                                     @ChannelID int,
                                                     @QTY int,
                                                     @CustCategoryNo int,
                                                     @PriceType int,
                                                     @CustomerDealerType int)
RETURNS table
AS
    RETURN (SELECT ISNULL(F.Price, ISNULL(R.SellingPrice, 0)) AS StandardPrice,
                   (SELECT DiscountLines.amount
                    FROM Customers
                         INNER JOIN CustDiscounts ON Customers.pricelist = CustDiscounts.no
                         INNER JOIN DiscountLines ON CustDiscounts.no = DiscountLines.no
                         INNER JOIN FinGoodsParent FP ON FP.Id = DiscountLines.FinGoods_ID
                    WHERE Customer_Code = @CustomerCode
                      AND CONVERT(date, CustDiscounts.startdate) <= @PricingDate
                      AND CONVERT(date, CustDiscounts.enddate) >= @PricingDate
                      AND DiscountLines.TYPE = @PriceType
                      AND FP.Id = @StockParentId) AS PricelistPrice,
                   (SELECT TOP 1
                           Pricing
                    FROM (SELECT Pricing
                          FROM PROMGEN
                               INNER JOIN FinGoodsParent FP ON FP.Id = PROMGEN.FinGoods_ID
                               INNER JOIN PromCateg ON PROMGEN.No = PromCateg.PromGen_No
                               INNER JOIN PromGen_Channels ON PROMGEN.No = PromGen_Channels.PromGen_No
                               INNER JOIN Channels ON PromGen_Channels.Channels_Id = Channels.Id
                          WHERE PROMGEN.MINQUANT <= @QTY
                            AND @PricingDate >= CONVERT(date, PROMGEN.START_DATE)
                            AND @PricingDate <= CONVERT(date, PROMGEN.END_DATE)
                            AND Channels_Id = @ChannelID
                            AND PromCateg.CustCateg_No = @CustCategoryNo
                            AND FP.Id = @StockParentId
                            AND PROMGEN.TYPE = @PriceType
                          UNION
                          SELECT MIN(SP_P.PricingRuleTypeAmount) AS Pricing
                          FROM StockParent_Promotions SP_P
                               INNER JOIN Promotions P ON P.Id = SP_P.Promotions_Id
                               INNER JOIN Promotions_Channels PC ON PC.Promotions_Id = P.Id
                               INNER JOIN StockParent SP ON SP_P.StockParent_Id = SP.Id
                               INNER JOIN Promotions_CustCateg PCC ON PCC.Promotions_Id = P.Id
                               INNER JOIN CUSTCATEG CC ON CC.NO = PCC.CustCateg_No
                          WHERE SP_P.MinPurchaseQuantity <= @QTY
                            AND @PricingDate >= CONVERT(date, P.DateValidFrom)
                            AND @PricingDate <= CONVERT(date, P.DateValidTo)
                            AND Channels_Id = @ChannelID
                            AND PCC.CustCateg_No = @CustCategoryNo
                            AND SP.Id = @StockParentId
                            AND SP_P.PricingRuleType = @PriceType
                            AND ((P.IsPromotionForEndUsers = 1
                              AND @CustomerDealerType = 1)
                              OR (P.IsPromotionForDealers = 1
                              AND @CustomerDealerType = 0))
                            AND P.IsDeleted = 0) OldAndNewPromotions
                    WHERE Pricing IS NOT NULL
                    ORDER BY Pricing ASC) AS PromotionPrice
            FROM StockParent
                 LEFT JOIN Fingoods F ON F.Id = StockParent.ID
                 LEFT JOIN RAWMAT R ON R.Id = StockParent.ID
            WHERE StockParent.Id = @StockParentId);
```

Comment: I must admit, that query looks significantly overly complicated. The lack of qualified columns makes it impossible for us to know if all the `JOIN`s are needed too. Those subqueries don't appear to be correlated either (I see no reference to the unaliased table `StockParent` though it could be in an unqualified column), which seems wrong. I would suggest that perhaps you need to take a step back and explain the problem you are actually trying to solve, and providing sample data and expected results

Comment: A subquery of this type can return a single value.

Comment: `@PricingDate <= CONVERT(date, P.DateValidTo)` This is not sargable - and likely a bad habit (or poor design). If DateValidTo is datetime, why? Does it actually have a time portion that is useful and used? You don't need to convert the upper bound logic at all - so a bit of a possible benefit by removing it.

Comment: That convert MIGHT be sargable if DateValidTo is a datetime. But it is likely not a [good idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)